# Code Crashes when loading an empty attribute from Cloudkit - using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I am trying to get access to a record value in CloudKit, here MyPin, it has a title & subtitle attribute/field value.
However it may happen that sometimes the record value is empty(here subtitle), and it crashes at the line when I call:

```
var tempS: String = Annot["Subtitle"] as! String
```

because `Annot["Subtitle"]` doesn exist ...

When I do

```
println(Annot["Subtitle"])
```

it returns nil

but if I do :

```
if (Annot["Subtitle"] == nil) {
println("just got a nil value")
}
```

I never enter the if statement:

Can someone help me how to identify if the record has an empty value?

Here is my line of codes:

```
let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()        
let publicData = container.publicCloudDatabase        
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyPin", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
if error == nil { // There is no error
for Annot in results {
var tempS: String = Annot["Subtitle"] as! String
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you get `Annot["Subtitle"]` it will give you a `CKRecordValue?` return which has a base class of `NSObjectProtocol`. So in your case the field does exist but it's not a String so casting it using as! String will crash your app. Since the field exists the `CKRecordValue` will not be nil. However the content of that field is nil. When you print the field, it will output the `.description` of that field. In your case that is nil. Could you try this code instead:

```
if let f = Annot["Subtitle"] {
   print("f = \(f) of type \(f.dynamicType)")
}
```

then set a breakpoint on the print line and when it stops try the following three statements in your output window:

```
po Annot
po f
p f
```

After the `po Annot` you should see what's in that record. Including your subtitle field. The `po f` is not so interesting. It will just output a memory address. The `p f` however will show you the actual type. If it's a string you should see something like: `(__NSCFConstantString *) $R3 = 0xafdd21e0`

P.S. Maybe you should call it record instead of Annot. It's a local variable so it should start with a lower case character. And it's still a record and not an Annot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing the right thing, but you don't see the println as it is executed in another thread (the completion part is executed asynchronously).
Try this:

```
if (Annot["Subtitle"] == nil) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    println("just got a nil value")
   }
}
```

and see if it works!

The way I get values from cloudkit is this way. This both take care of the nil values and all other eventualities. Just note I have implemented a delegate to get my results back to the calling object asynchronously

```
privateDB.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            for record in result{
                let rec = record as! CKRecord
                if let xxxVar = rec.valueForKey("fieldName") as? String{
                    myArray.append( xxxVar! )  //append unwrapped xxxVar to some result or whatever
                }else{
                    //handle nil value
                }
             }
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //do something with you data
                self.delegate?.myResultCallBack(myArray)
                return
             }                   
        }else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.delegate?.myErrorCallBack(error)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Beware, there are some changes in Swift2

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no luck with that, still not printing it :-(